# Best way to map a mysql table to new table with different field names

Tags: php, mysql, migration, mapping

I'm facing a migration problem on the job. Right now we have a single database which is used by our website and by a backoffice tool.
As part of trying to improve our code in the website, we've desgined a new schema for several tables in the database.

As an example let's take the products table. It's fairly standard with fields like description, name, product code, price, creation date etc. We now have a new table, let's call it better_products. The problem is, we can change the website code all we want, but we can't touch the backoffice tool's code which relies heavily on the old products table.

We're going to end up in a situation in production where the backoffice tool is writing to the old products table, and the website is reading from the new better_products table. The question is, how do we keep both of them in sync? I've been googling around for some time now, and by far the most common solution is to use triggers, and map the incoming data to the new table. I've written the AFTER INSERT trigger for the products, but when I went to write the UPDATE trigger it turned out there's no way to iterate over the fields that changed inside the trigger and map them over. This means writing out the fields by hand a la 'IF NEW.fieldName <> OLD.fieldName THEN' which is ugly and requires listing the fields out by hand.

Is there a better way? a semi-better way? anything except writing this out field by field?
Is there a better practice than using triggers?

Please don't suggest changing the backoffice tool as this is not a realistic option right now. It's planned, but not soon enough for us to be able to wait for it.

Comment: what about using views? and only using the view in the backoffice application.. like `create view as foo SELECT IF(new.fieldName <> oldFieldNAme, whatever, else) as fieldNameYouWant ....`

Comment: Are the rows in the new system effectively read-only, or is the new system storing data in them that must be preserved between UPDATEs from the backoffice system?

Comment: @busse The website only reads from these tables but the backoffice reads **and** writes.

Comment: @Rufinus As I mentioned, I cannot touch the backoffice tool for at least another 2.5-3 months which is too long for me because we'll have our fresh tables in prod very soon.

Comment: Deleted my answer because JeffO's is right given you aren't writing in the web side. Just make the new table a view of the old table until you can rewrite the backoffice tool.

Comment: @developerwjk - the data in the underlying table of a view can be updated especially for a single table query. MySQL may not allow that.

Comment: @JeffO, I thought MySQL couldn't, but looks like it can. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: Why don't you just update the entire record in the new table based on the mapped fields from the current table? How many times does a record get updated when actually none of the values of any of the fields have changed? Just base it off of the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a view in the mysql database called better_products that is a select statement on the old product but with aliases for the column names that have changed.

Eventually, you can update the code in the backoffice app, to use this view. Once both systems are using the new view, that view can be replaced by an actual table called better_products that has all the data from the old table copied over.

Comment: So basically the website will read it's data from the view? How would this impact performance on the website side of things?

Comment: It's a single table query, so there shouldn't be much of a performance hit. I can't speak for mysql, but most rdbms can handle it.

Comment: After discussing with teammates we decided to go with triggers generated by script, but I chose your answer because it seems like a good way to go and maybe useful to other people.